# Can I have both iAds and Admob on my app?

Tags: ios, iad, ads

I recently added iAd on my app, then I realized that iAds isn't available in my country. Most  of my users are in my country, so iAds is useless for me.

I'm wondering If I can put Admob in my app once the `didFailToReceiveAdWithError:` method is being called? Will this cause any problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Yes.

I've done it in one of my apps, which I shall refrain from linking to here. What I did was exactly what you're thinking of, showing a different ad provider (AdMob) in place of iAd when an iAd wasn't available. I've been doing this for months, several updates, and no problem.

If you want to be safe, just make sure that iAd has supremacy over the other providers - that way, there's no reason for Apple to complain.